# One Result Activity with many Activities

Tags: android

I have many activities which have 1 resultant activity. Does anyone know how to separate it, the result will display one result from many activity. If i run it it will display result `fruitQuestion` and `AnimalQuestion`.

Test.java:

```
public class Test extends Activity {
    Button btnFruitQ,btnAnimalQ;
    ToggleButton tb;

    public static boolean tbflag;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        btnFruitQ = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFruitQ);
        btnAnimalQ = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnimalQ);
        tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton);
        btnFruitQ.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tbflag=tb.isChecked();
                startActivity(new Intent(Test.this, FruitQuestion.class));
            }
        });
        btnAnimalQ.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tbflag=tb.isChecked();
                startActivity(new Intent(Test.this, AnimalQuestion.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

FruitQuestion.java:

```
public class FruitQuestion extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    Button btnNext;
    RadioGroup rg;
    RadioButton bt1,bt2,bt3;
    String Question[]={"HAHA","HAHA2","HAHA3"};
    String ans[]={"i1","12","i3"};
    String opt[]={"i1","lali","uu","12","hehe","oo","i3","jj","cc"};

    int flag=0;
    public static int mark,correct,wrong;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fruit_question);

        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvque);
        btnNext=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg);
        bt1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        bt2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        bt3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btn3);

        tv.setText(Question[flag]);
        bt1.setText(opt[0]);
        bt2.setText(opt[1]);
        bt3.setText(opt[2]);

        Toast.makeText(this,"Negative Mark : "+Test.tbflag,1000).show();
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RadioButton uans=(RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                String ansText= uans.getText().toString();

                if (ansText.equalsIgnoreCase(ans[flag]))
                {
                    correct++;
                }
                else
                {
                    wrong++;
                }
                flag++;
                if(flag<Question.length)
                {
                    tv.setText(Question[flag]);
                    bt1.setText(opt[flag*3]);
                    bt2.setText(opt[(flag*3)+1]);
                    bt3.setText(opt[(flag*3)+2]);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(Test.tbflag)
                    {
                        mark=correct-wrong;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mark=correct;
                    }
                    Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_fruit_question, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

ResultActivity.java:

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    Button btnRestart;
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvres);
        btnRestart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRestart);


            sb.append("Correct Answer : " + FruitQuestion.correct);
            sb.append("\nWrong Answer : " + FruitQuestion.wrong);
            sb.append("\nFinal Score : " + FruitQuestion.mark);
            tv.setText(sb);
            FruitQuestion.correct = 0;
            FruitQuestion.wrong = 0;

        sb.append("Correct Answer : "+AnimalQuestion.correct);
        sb.append("\nWrong Answer : "+AnimalQuestion.wrong);
        sb.append("\nFinal Score : " + AnimalQuestion.mark);
        tv.setText(sb);
        AnimalQuestion.correct=0;
        AnimalQuestion.wrong=0;

        btnRestart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Test.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_result, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What I understand is you want to show results from different activities in your single `ResultActivity` right ?

Comment: Please share the code of your other activities where you are conducting questions and answers

Comment: Just add an additional Extra to each intent that will tell `ResultActivity` which Activity started it.

Comment: @DanielNugent ummm can you give me the example using ResultActivity. sorry still noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Intent Extras to tell `ResultActivity` which Activity called it, and display the corresponding results.

Note that you should also re-factor your code so that you're not using static variables in the Activities to store data, you could use SharedPreferences instead.

Just to get you started though, here is what you could do in the short term:

In `FruitQuestion`, you would have:

```
    Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("question", "fruit");
    startActivity(in);
```

And in `AnimalQuestion`, you would have:

```
    Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("question", "animal");
    startActivity(in);
```

Then, in `ResultActivity`, capture the Intent Extra, and show corresponding result:

```
    Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null){
        String question = extras.getString("question");
        if (question.equals("fruit")) {
            sb.append("Correct Answer : " + FruitQuestion.correct);
            sb.append("\nWrong Answer : " + FruitQuestion.wrong);
            sb.append("\nFinal Score : " + FruitQuestion.mark);
            tv.setText(sb);
            FruitQuestion.correct = 0;
            FruitQuestion.wrong = 0;
        }
        else if (question.equals("animal")) {
            sb.append("Correct Answer : " + AnimalQuestion.correct);
            sb.append("\nWrong Answer : " + AnimalQuestion.wrong);
            sb.append("\nFinal Score : " + AnimalQuestion.mark);
            tv.setText(sb);
            AnimalQuestion.correct = 0;
            AnimalQuestion.wrong = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: when put Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("question", "fruit");
    startActivity(in);. it's directly jump to resulty activity without doing activity fruit quiz

Comment: @AdityaWicaksono  You need to do it in the `onClick()` event of the Next button, just as you do in the code in your question.

Comment: you might have placed the code in `onCreate`. You have to place it inside `onClick`

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand you, you want to pass some values from A-activity to B-activity.

To pass data between activities, you can use the same intent you are sending.
Here an example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
i.putExtra("key1", value1);
i.putExtra("key2", value2);
startActivity(i);
```

putExtra method allow pass multiples kinds of value, like boolean, string, integer...

Then, in the another activity, in onCreate method, you can get this value this way:

```
String save = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key1");
```

Or

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
boolean check = bundle.getBoolean("key2");
```

I hope it help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, give your `Intent` instance a different name. Other than `in`. You can put extra in intent object and send it to `ResultActivity`

Like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("activityName", "FruitQuestion");
startActivity(intent);
```

In `ResultActivity`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String activityName = intent.getStringExtra("activityName");
```

Check your `activityName` value and show its results.